# Run reindex via ssh - magento 2.1

Tags: magento-2.1, php, ssh

I am trying to create button to run php ../bin/magento indexer:reindex bash script via admin panel. It is working on my localhost but when I pushed the script on server nothing happens.

```
<?php if ($title == "Index Management") : ?>
    <a href="?reindex">Reindex</a>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['reindex'])) {
        echo shell_exec('php ../bin/magento indexer:reindex');
        echo '<br>';
        //echo '<strong>Reindex finished successfully.</strong>';
    }
if(function_exists('exec')) {
    echo "exec is enabled";
} else {
    echo "exec is disabled";
}
echo '<br>';
echo shell_exec('whoami');
```

It says that "exec is enabled" and whoami says "www-data".
Maybe that www-data doesn't have permissions to execute that command. What do you guys $think?

Answer (score 2):

In server, If you don't have enough permission to execute I am using the below script (it's not a good way but It works ! ) , maybe It helps you

just simply create a new file in your root server(Let's call it `custom.php`), then write the below code in this file

`system('php bin/magento cache:status');` // you can change it to your command

And run this script with `http://your base url/custom.php`

It will give you result in output.

---

Another way, but it doesn't give you any message(I mean success or fail), but you can use it if you don't have any option.

For that, you have to create a new file(Let's call it `custom1.php`), and write the below code in your file.

```
<?php

use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$state = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');
$k[0]='bin/magento';
$k[1]='cache:status'; // write your proper command like setup:upgrade,cache:enable etc...
$_SERVER['argv']=$k;
try {
    $handler = new \Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler();
    set_error_handler([$handler, 'handler']);
    $application = new Magento\Framework\Console\Cli('Magento CLI');
    $application->run();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    while ($e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        echo $e->getTraceAsString();
        echo "\n\n";
        $e = $e->getPrevious();
    }
}
```

And run this script with `http://your base url/custom1.php`

It is not a good way but sometimes It helps.

Comment: It returns error that he can't find app/bootstrap file, are you sure we can add this script to the magento 2?

Comment: No It is not good way to put this script in Magento 2 root directory, but sometime I am using this script If I don't have any options to execute command :) @Milo

Comment: Please check path of require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';

Comment: Have you tried first way ?, but just writing only system('php bin/magento cache:status');

Comment: Can you please tell me how to create button to call this file from the root? <a href="somemagentoroot()/custom1.php">Link</a>

Comment: I did try it with system, but I got the same result as with shell_exec

Comment: Ahh, then I think second might be trick for you

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have changed the owner of var/generation folder myuser:myuser, and now it allows executing the reindex command.